# In Spark AR, how do I setup a looping animation to play for a specific duration using patches?

Tags: animation, spark-ar-studio

I have a character with a looping idle animation at start, when the user screen taps I want a different looping animation to play for 3 seconds before switching back to idle.

Ideally, this would be using the animation blend patches.

I would like the walking animation to be triggered by screen tap and screen pan, I have the setup for screen pan working already, but I am a noob and cannot figure out how to add the logic for the screen tap setup.

Any help would be much appreciated!